# Recalcular precio producto en Woocomerce en la plantilla de emails

Tags: php, woocommerce

He estado usando el plugin de NQR Quotes para que genere los prespuesto del carrito.
De esta forma pude cambiar como se calula el precio final de cada producto en funcion de la direccion de envio.
Parte del codigo con el que se realiza el calculo es el siguiente:

```
        add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_discount', 'vp_add_sub_total', 10 );
    function vp_add_sub_total( $order_id ) 
    {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><?php _e('Precio')?>:</td>
            <td width="1%"></td>
            <td class="total"><?php echo wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
```

Lo que realiza el codigo es lo siguiente: al pedir un producto y dar la direccion de envio  da el precio final que es la suma del envio con el precio de venta del producto. Luego con mas codigo se oculta todo lo que no corresponde sin modificar woocomerce.

Ahora en la plantilla de woocommerce en emails-order-items.php he añadido este codigo:

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?>
  <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item, $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() )) ); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

En este momento me calcula el precio iva incluido pero quiero sumar el precio sin iva con el coste de envio en el producto.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Les pido por favor que antes de poner una nota negativa lo lean varias veces y en caso de que no se entienda se podria borra , soy conciente que lo que estoy realizando es complejo y tengan paciencia. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Despues de analizar nuevamente el codigo he encontrado la clave de la resolucion del problema. Es mas simple de lo que podria pensar:

El codigo que considero puede servir a mas gente es el siguiente:

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?>
  <?php echo wp_kses_post(**************, array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() )) ); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

De tal manera que en donde estan los asteriscos se puede poner cualquier calculo.
Agradesco las aclaraciones y ayudas de los usuarios LoicTheAztec y a SeoSiteSoft con los cuales no hubiera podido cambar tantas cosas en Woocommerce.